# pass variable when click button in js

Tags: javascript, html

I have a problem to pass variable in js!
I have two html page and each of html page has a js script. I want when click a button in first html a variable pass to another js file.

my first html(index.html) is :

```js
// test.js

var vari;
document.getElementById("btn").addEventListener("click", function() {
  vari = 10;
  window.location.href = "./index2.html";
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>
  <p>test</p>
  <button id="btn">click</button>

  <script src="./test.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

and script of this html is (test.js):

I want when click to btn go to html2(index2.html) and and vari pass to js2(test2.js)!

my html2(index2.html) is :

```js
// test.js
var vari;
document.getElementById("btn").addEventListener("click", function() {
  vari = 10;
  window.location.href = "./index2.html";
});

// test2.js
console.log(vari);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>

    <script src="./test.js"></script>
    <script src="./test2.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

But in test2.js vari is undefined.
How can I solve this problem?

Comment: As you can see you get an error. You need to test if the element `btn`  is there - since it is not there and not clicked, the vari is not set

Comment: Possible duplicate of: [How do I share a global variable between multiple files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46476426/how-do-i-share-a-global-variable-between-multiple-files)

Comment: @Dexygen How is that a dupe? window.globalVar will disappear at the location change.OP is not using node or react btw

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Save the variable in sessionStorage. Instead of

```
vari = 10;
```

do

```
sessionStorage.vari = 10;
```

And then you can retrieve it in `test2.js`:

```
console.log(sessionStorage.vari);
```

Note that storage will always contain a *string*. If the type matters, make sure to transform back to a number:

```
const vari = Number(sessionStorage.vari);
```

For an even more general solution, to transfer any sort of serializable data, use `JSON.stringify` when saving and `JSON.parse` when retrieving.

Comment: So `sessionStorage.setItem("vari",10)` can be written as `sessionStorage.vari = 10;` ? (I am not the downvoter)

Comment: Yes, I prefer dot notation, it's more concise

Comment: But then you do Number(sessionStorage.vari) instead of +sessionStorage.vari :)

Comment: Being concise is often over-rated.  If you use the interface's `setItem` and `getItem` methods for instance, you can easily grep your code for anywhere storage is being utilized.

Comment: @Dexygen grepping for *Storage should do the same, no?

Comment: @mplungjan Not necessarily, some people assign it to a variable first, then use that as their reference

Comment: If you voted it down because of personal grepping preferences, then you are harsh